# Split col data on nth space and return both sides of the split

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm transferring data from an old (very not-normalised) database to a new one.  I need to split a name column that contains an inconsistent number of elements.  So I need to split on the last space such that after that space is the last name and before that space is the first name, even if it contains 'Dave & Sue'.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX( Name, ' ', -1 )
```

That gets me the last name but please help me with returning the data before the split.  In some instances I will need to split on the first space, others on the second and some on 3rd 4th or 5th. ALways the last space though.  I'd like to get more familiar with substring_index etc and if possible to achieve this with standard SQL rather than splitting in perl/php which would be a lot more straightforward. (for me)

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( Name, ' ', -1 ) postfix,
       TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX( Name, ' ', -1 ) FROM Name) prefix`, for example...

Comment: Take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/791c4ffe-e243-490e-a1d1-cc994e348b7b/finding-last-occurrence-of-a-space-in-a-string?forum=transactsql

Comment: Thank you both. That's given me TRIM & TRAILING to get my head into this evening :)  I had tried reverse wrapped in a second reverse, without success but didn't persist long enough :(